# Erro al correr docker-compose

Tags: laravel, docker, lumen

Hola estoy tratando de instalar docker con lumen, postgres y nginx pero cuando trato de correr docker-compose me arroja lo siguiente

> OSError: Can not read file in context: \?\C:\Users\PalixAdmin\Desktop\test-docker\src\vendor\bin\carbon

mi docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/src
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

y mi dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3-cli-buster 
CMD php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t /src/public
```

Comment: Podrías revisar los permisos del fichero que falla? Por otro lado tienes suficiente espacio en disco? Esos parecen ser los errores mas comunes, aparte de referenciar ficheros que estén fuera de src

Comment: Tienes un `Dockerfile` en la misma carpeta que el `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: si estan en la misma carpeta